# Can not access / click Button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, button

On the following Website [Forge](https://www.outsystems.com/forge/list?q=&t=&o=most-popular&tr=False&oss=False&c=%205361,5362,5363,5364,5365,5366,5367,5368,5369,5370,5381,5382,5383,5384,5385,5386,5387,5388,5389,5390,5391,3485,5392,5393&a=&v=&hd=False&tn=&scat=forge), I need to access the Load more button (at the bottom of the component list) multiple times, to scrape the list of available components. While I am able to access any element that I need, I struggle to access the button directly and then click it.

When using

```
button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="PortalTheme_wt778_block_wtMainContent_wtLoadMore"]')
button.click()
```

I get the element. However, I cannot click it.

I have no experience in web development, and I am new to web scraping. Thus, I am struggling to find out what exactly is going wrong here.

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to click this button!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until <kbd>Load More</kbd> is ready to be clicked. Use Selenium's [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) to perform action on the desired button.

Refer code below which will use `Explicit Waits` to click <kbd>Load More</kbd>:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver =  webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.outsystems.com/forge/list?q=&t=&o=most-popular&tr=False&oss=False&c=%205361,5362,5363,5364,5365,5366,5367,5368,5369,5370,5381,5382,5383,5384,5385,5386,5387,5388,5389,5390,5391,3485,5392,5393&a=&v=&hd=False&tn=&scat=forge")
driver.maximize_window()

# Create wait object to wait for 20s
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)

# Click on Accept cookies button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()

# Click on Load more button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='PortalTheme_wt778_block_wtMainContent_wtLoadMore']"))).click()
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I will try in a Minute as I am currently on my way, but I don’t understand how I am already able to retrieve the object via XPath but then being able to click it. If the object was not already loaded by then, how come I can retrieve it?